# How can i display parallely updated record id from mysql using curl with jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, curl

I am getting some wrong display with updated records in mysql. My requirement is there are 4 process in my webpage. First user clicks on process one ( i am calling this as round one) some records start update in database. At the same time i want to show which record updated to User. For this i used curl and jquery.I am getting output but that was not in correct. At the time of updating i am inserting updated time using the below code.

```
<?php  

   $microtime = microtime(true);
   $microtime_replace = str_replace('.','',$microtime); 

?>
```

So for each record updated time in microsecods will be insert in database like microseconds "5134", "6000","6789" like this.When user clicks on Start Round one button i am calling one javascript function for executing updated process in ajax call.That javascript function is StartRoundOne(). In this function i am calling

```
setInterval(function(){displayUpdatedIds()},100);
```

In displayUpdatedIds() i am calling curl process.

```
function displayUpdatedIds()
{
   jQuery.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       crossDomain:true,
       async: false,
       url: "curlProcess.php",
       success: function(valid_result){

                      if(valid_result){
                        jQuery("#UpdatedIds").html(valid_result)  ;
                      }                 
                }
    });  
}
```

In UpdatedIds div tag those ids will display.

The code in **curlProcess.php**

```
<?php

   $the_url = $path./getUpdatedIds.php;
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $the_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $result;

?>
```

Below code i am trying to get updated ids for displaying one by one from 
getUpdatedIds.php file.

```
$reconciledpid = getdata("temp_table","pid","round_status='R1_DONE' and last_updated = (select max(last_updated) FROM temp_table where round_status='R1_DONE' order by pid asc limit 0,1)");
echo $reconciledpid;
```

In database records are properly updated with last_updated time.like

```
firstrecord at 3456 micro seconds
second record at 4000 micro seconds.
third record at 4500 micro seconds.
fourth record at 4890 micro seconds.
fifth record at 5300 micro seconds.
```

like this. At the time of executing for every 100 microseconds
displayUpdatedIds() will call and get the updated ids. But for me i am not 
getting all the updated ids one by one.

The output what i am expecting is (in database all the records updated order by id)
for example in that table i am having total of 7 records. My desired out put is
just i am showing one by one.

```
 1/10 
 2/10
 3/10
 4/10
 5/10
 6/10
 7/10
```

Some updated ids skipped , don't know why this happend.
But i am getting like this

```
2/10
4/10
5/10
7/10
```

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong. Sorry for my bad english if there any typos.
I need parallely updated record need to display to user.